# What to set "intercept factor" and "slope factor" as in model?

Tags: r, modeling, statistical-power, structural-equation-modeling, intercept

I was struggling a bit with understanding what exactly the intercept factor and slope factor is in a model. I need to estimate these in an a priori power analysis I am trying to do.

My understanding is that a "high" intercept would be 1, with the slope being the rate of change (either positive or negative). I noticed you can set the intercept above 1, and wondered when this would be the case. What is the difference between an intercept factor of 1 and 2? Is an intercept factor of 1 with a slope of -0.1 the same as an intercept factor of 2 with a slope of -0.2, for example.

How does the intercept change depending on the observed measure, if at all?

Added R code below. Latent variable is depression, with observed measure of PHQ-9 scores collected at 7 timepoints. I plan to analyse this with a latent growth curve model.

```
library(semPower)
powerLGCM <- semPower.powerLGCM(
  # define type of power analysis
  type = 'a-priori', alpha = .05, power = .80,
  # define hypothesis 
  nWaves = 7,
  means = c(1, -0.15),     # i, s
  variances = c(.8, .7),  # i, s
  covariances = .5,
  nullEffect = 'sMean = 0',
  # define measurement model
  nIndicator = rep(1, 7), loadM = .7
)
```

Comment: This rather depends on the model you are planning to estimate. Can you provide more details? (But essentially it's the same as the slope and intercept in regression. You just have each person measured mutiple times, instead of once, as you do in regression).

Comment: I am planning to estimate a latent growth model to analyse changes in depression, as indicated by PHQ-9 scores collected at 7 intervals. 
I also plan to use predictors to analyse whether curves are different for different populations within the sample (e.g male vs female, high scores on adhd questionnaire vs low scores), although I have not included this in the power analysis as I am initially just trying to calculate the sample required to plot a slope.
I added my current R code to the main body.

Comment: You don't need power to plot a slope. You need power to test a null hypothesis. I'm not familiar with semPower but from reading the help file, it appears that you need to use the betaST or betaIT options.  I'm not a huge fan of this sort of wrapper function, I prefer to code a simulation myself so that I know that I understand what it is doing.

Comment: I think the `simsem` package provides the flexibility Jeremy prefers.  You can find vignettes on the web site about power analysis for model fit/comparison: https://github.com/simsem/simsem/wiki/Vignette However, if you are interested in power for testing specific parameters, the `summaryParam()` function provides that for `sim()` output (see the `?summaryParam` help-page example).

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest that you read a bit more about latent growth curve (LGC) models before you run your power analysis. This will help you understand what the parameters of an LGC model are, how they relate to your observed variables, and how to set the parameters appropriately for your power analysis. There is a lot of good introductory literature available on this topic, for example:

Bollen, K. A., & Curran, P. J. (2006). Latent curve models: A structural equation perspective. New York: Wiley.

Duncan, T. E., Duncan, S. C., & Strycker, L. A. (2013). An introduction to latent variable growth curve modeling: Concepts, issues, and application. Routledge.

Little, T. D. (2013). Longitudinal structural equation modeling. New York: Guilford.

Newsom, J. T. (2015). Longitudinal structural equation modeling: A comprehensive introduction. Routledge.

Preacher, K. J. (2008). Latent growth curve modeling (No. 157). Sage.

https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=1ACF96E33449B682E740E025BEAF408E?doi=10.1.1.138.4268&rep=rep1&type=pdf

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4_FE9Q5LCo

In a nutshell, an LGC model, in the simple linear growth case consists of an intercept factor (initial or Time-1 latent variable) that represents the depression true (error-free) scores at Time 1, a linear slope factor (latent variable) that represents true inter-individual differences in linear change across time, and time-specific error variables that represent random measurement error and situation-specific variance.

The intercept and slope factors each have a mean and a variance as free parameters as indicated in your syntax. The intercept factor mean represents the average depression true (error-free) scores at Time 1. The variance of the intercept factor represents true (error-free) individual differences in depression at Time 1. The slope factor can be interpreted as a latent difference or latent change score variable that represents linear change in true scores across time. The mean of the slope factor represents the average rate of linear change in true scores across time. The variance of the slope factor represents the extent of inter-individual differences in linear change across time.

There is also a covariance parameter between intercept and slope that represents the linear association between the true initial status and linear change over time. Lastly, there are error variance parameters to be set for the observed variables. The error variances reflect the degree of unreliability and/or situation-specificity in the observed variables.

It may be difficult for you to guess the "right" (or at least plausible) parameter values for your simulation. (This is probably the hardest part of any kind of power analysis!) You might want to check out whether there is any prior literature that has reported an LGC model application to the same depression scale. Perhaps you can derive approximate parameter values from such an application. In any case, I would try out multiple different sets of parameter values to see how that affects estimated power, especially if you are not sure about what the actual parameters might look like in the population.

Comment: So regarding the estimated parameter of the mean intercept and mean slope, does this relate to the observed variable? For example, I expect the average PHQ-9 score in this study to be around 20 at first interval with a moderate variance. However if I change the mean intercept to 20, with an expected slope of -1. The power analysis using the code estimated 10 participants provides 0.88 Power, which just doesn't sound right to me and made me figure my understanding was wrong. Is this actually correct?

Comment: The means of the intercept and slope refer to the means of the latent factors. They are not identical to the observed variable means. However, the observed means can serve as a guide for finding plausible/realistic values for the intercept and slope factor means. It is plausible that the intercept factor mean is not too far away from the Time 1 observed variable mean. Regarding the slope factor mean, you have to ask yourself whether it is plausible that the average rate of linear decline between two time points is -1. In any case, I would not estimate an LGCM with only N = 10 cases.

Comment: Also, you have to make sure your simulated values for the latent factor variances and the error variances are plausible/realistic. This can be more tricky, especially with regard to the slope factor variance.

Comment: Thanks Christian, this is really helpful.